# Instrument crash at startup appium

Tags: ios, iphone, automation, appium, xcode6.1

[image: Instrument crashed at startup while run Appium tool.]

Am trying to run appium tool for testing apps. While starting appium server i finished all setting right way. When appium running the app will start at time but suddently it get crash.

Yes.Am using Xcode 6.0 and Appium 1.3.4

Comment: Do you have both latest xcode and latest appium installed?

Comment: To run in simualtor --> use simulator build, NOT archived build.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51443937/1522584

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the .app file you are using is build for simulator if you are running appium for simulator and a different build i.e the build for device if you want to run it into real device....This is one of the cause which causes the instruments to crash at start up.

Answer (score 0):

When I create an new project with XCode then generate the app file, it is working fine - I can open the inspector. 
But I have a problem when I use an already developed application and the build is coming from a developer profile : I can't open the inspector and instruments crash on startup.

Answer (score 0):

While running the script please start xcode and go in the settings of the mobile device and find developer options. Make sure UIAutomation is enabled there. If it is not then enable it and after it try to run the script again. Surely it will work.